# XSL last-day-of-month function for BI Publisher report

Tags: xml, xslt, rtf, peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I'm creating a report in Microsoft word using the BI Publisher tool which uses XSL to create a PDF. The data is created from a SQL query in Peoplesoft which is then exported in an XML file. When there is an XML field that is empty (''), I want the report to fill in the field with the last day of the month from today's day.

I saw XSL has a function for this

```
<xsl:function name="functx:last-day-of-month" as="xs:date?"
              xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:anyAtomicType?"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="
   functx:date(year-from-date(xs:date($date)),
            month-from-date(xs:date($date)),
            functx:days-in-month($date))
  "/>    
</xsl:function>
```

http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_last-day-of-month.html

I'm not sure how to implement this with my current XSL. I figured out how to display today's date like this

```
<?format-date:xdoxslt:sysdate_as_xsdformat();'Short'?>
```

Is there anyway to use the XSL `functx:last-day-of-month` with the XSL field of today's date? I haven't found a good example of this anywhere online.

I could rewrite my SQL query with case statements, but doing this in Peoplesoft is very tedious and making this change with XSL would make my life a lot easier. I don't know much about how XSL works, so anything helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `functx` function is an external library you can download [here](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/download.html). Put this file in the same directory and include it with the following two lines in your XSLT file (at least `version="2.0"`) is required.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" 
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:import href="functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xsl" />
...
```

Now you can use the `functx:...` functions in your XSLT file.
For example, to get the `current-date()` use

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-date()" />
```

And to get the `last-day-of-month(...)` use

```
<xsl:value-of select="functx:last-day-of-month(xs:date('2018-07-19'))" />
```

> Is there anyway to use the XSL functx:last-day-of-month with the XSL field of today's date? I haven't found a good example of this anywhere online.

Combining both to get the `last-day-of-month()` or the `current-date()` use

```
<xsl:value-of select="functx:last-day-of-month(current-date())" />
```